# How to transmit light ideally through not parallel tiny holes within a metal case?

Tags: visible-light, diffraction, lenses

I currently try to transmit light through a tiny hole of one side of a metal case in order to receive the light on the other side of the case. The tiny holes are not parallel (see image 2).
[image]

Using the torch light (1000lumen) I receive a  very tiny amount of light through hole 2. I was also trying to use convex lenses

1. In front of the torch light to increase/brighten the light source
2. In front of hole 2 in order to receive more light from hole2

Both ways there I did not experience any  significant improvement considering the light amount coming out of hole 2.

Is there a way I may get a better amount of light through hole 2?

Is there any recommendable lens or anything else I may have to do?

Laser light are known to be narrow and intense; so is it possible to turn an LED light of a torch to such a strong light source? This might be a solution to my problem...

The diameter of the hole is arrnd 3mm 2.The case is arrnd 7cm thick It would be great if there is a realiable solution whilst the light will be transmitted from one particular angle/ or few angles.

Comment: What is your hole diameter? How thick are the case walls? Do you need the system to work for any angle of torchlight illumination, or is perpendicular illumination all you care about?

Comment: Do you have the option to place a lens inside the box? Because a convex lens focusing hole 1 onto hole 2 would greatly improve your light transmission.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast
1.The diameter of the hole is arrnd 3mm
2.The case is arrnd 7cm thick
3. The perfect solution would be that it works from any angle;
   However, a decent solution would still be one particular angle/ few angles
   whilst it should be reliable that it always work from that angle/angles

Comment: @Floris  I dont have the option to place anything inside the box

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to aim the torch at the second hole, tho' due to the angular spread you'll still dump most of the light. Replace the torch with a laser pointer and aim that at the second hole & nearly all the light will get thru.

You might consider a light pipe such as a large-diameter optical fiber, plugged into both holes so that all light entering the fiber exits the other hole.

Your setup seems very odd, to say the least.  If you could explain what you're trying to achieve and why the box has to be there, we could give a better solution.

Comment: Thx for your input!
1. I was also thinking about a laser light.
Is it possible turn the beam of a torch light 
as strong and narrow as the one from a laser??

2. Well the idea will not work since there is no
possiblity to put anything within the box.

3. What I try to do is a small robot 
that should be  controlled via led light.
The image I provided depicts a simple view on my Setup considering the issue I have
with the weak light getting transferred to the other side

Comment: To ur 1st suggestion, is there a way not to dump most of the light? Herefore I guess the light must be narrow and intense as the one from a laser pointer..